# Can't install Imagemagick on Mountain Lion

Tags: imagemagick, homebrew, osx-mountain-lion, librsvg

Yesterday I updated to Mountain Lion and I wanted to start my rails app and had some problems with Rmagick gem. After reading on the net I did the following :

- Installed Xcode 4.4
- Installed developper tools
- Installed Xquartz
- Uninstalled imagemagick using brew
- Installed imagemagick with brew

During this installation I receive an error :

> coders/svg.c:93:10: fatal error: 'librsvg/rsvg.h' file not found

***Full log***

```
 ==> Downloading http://downloads.sf.net/project/machomebrew/mirror/ImageMagick-6.7.7-   6.tar.bz2
    Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/imagemagick-6.7.7-6.tar.bz2
==> Patching
patching file configure
Hunk #1 succeeded at 32371 (offset 447 lines).
==> ./configure --disable-osx-universal-binary --without-perl --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.7-6 --enable-shared --disable-st
==> make install
/bin/sh ./config/mkinstalldirs . ltdl/
cp ./ltdl/argz_.h ltdl/argz.h-t
mv ltdl/argz.h-t ltdl/argz.h
make  install-am
  CC     ltdl/argz.lo
  CC     coders/coders_tga_la-tga.lo
  CC     coders/coders_thumbnail_la-thumbnail.lo
  CC     coders/coders_tile_la-tile.lo
  CC     coders/coders_tim_la-tim.lo
  CC     coders/coders_ttf_la-ttf.lo
  CC     coders/coders_txt_la-txt.lo
  CC     coders/coders_uil_la-uil.lo
  CC     coders/coders_url_la-url.lo
  CC     coders/coders_uyvy_la-uyvy.lo
  CC     coders/coders_vicar_la-vicar.lo
  CC     coders/coders_vid_la-vid.lo
  CC     coders/coders_viff_la-viff.lo
  CC     coders/coders_wbmp_la-wbmp.lo
  CC     coders/coders_wpg_la-wpg.lo
  CC     coders/coders_xbm_la-xbm.lo
  CC     coders/coders_xc_la-xc.lo
  CC     coders/coders_xcf_la-xcf.lo
  CC     coders/coders_xpm_la-xpm.lo
  CC     coders/coders_xps_la-xps.lo
  CC     coders/coders_ycbcr_la-ycbcr.lo
  CC     coders/coders_yuv_la-yuv.lo
  CC     coders/coders_jpeg_la-jpeg.lo
  CC     coders/coders_jp2_la-jp2.lo
  CC     coders/coders_png_la-png.lo
  CC     coders/coders_ept_la-ept.lo
  CC     coders/coders_tiff_la-tiff.lo
  CC     coders/coders_x_la-x.lo
  CC     coders/coders_xwd_la-xwd.lo
  CC     coders/coders_aai_la-aai.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-accelerate.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-animate.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-annotate.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-artifact.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-attribute.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-blob.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-cache.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-cache-view.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-cipher.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-client.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-coder.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-color.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-colormap.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-colorspace.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-compare.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-composite.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-compress.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-configure.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-constitute.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-decorate.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-delegate.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-deprecate.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-display.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-distort.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-draw.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-effect.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-enhance.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-exception.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-feature.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-fourier.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-fx.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-gem.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-geometry.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-hashmap.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-histogram.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-identify.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-image.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-image-view.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-layer.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-list.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-locale.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-log.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-magic.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-magick.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-matrix.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-memory.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-mime.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-module.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-monitor.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-montage.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-morphology.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-option.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-paint.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-pixel.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-policy.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-PreRvIcccm.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-prepress.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-property.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-profile.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-quantize.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-quantum.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-quantum-export.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-quantum-import.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-random.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-registry.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-resize.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-resample.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-resource.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-segment.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-semaphore.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-shear.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-signature.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-splay-tree.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-static.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-statistic.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-stream.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-string.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-thread.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-timer.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-token.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-transform.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-threshold.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-type.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-utility.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-version.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-widget.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-xml-tree.lo
  CC     magick/magick_libMagickCore_la-xwindow.lo
  CC     ltdl/loaders/ltdl_libltdlc_la-preopen.lo
  CC     ltdl/ltdl_libltdlc_la-lt__alloc.lo
  CC     ltdl/ltdl_libltdlc_la-lt_dlloader.lo
  CC     ltdl/ltdl_libltdlc_la-lt_error.lo
  CC     ltdl/ltdl_libltdlc_la-ltdl.lo
  CC     ltdl/ltdl_libltdlc_la-slist.lo
  CC     ltdl/loaders/dlopen.lo
  CC     coders/coders_art_la-art.lo
  CC     coders/coders_avs_la-avs.lo
  CC     coders/coders_bgr_la-bgr.lo
  CC     coders/coders_bmp_la-bmp.lo
  CC     coders/coders_braille_la-braille.lo
  CC     coders/coders_cals_la-cals.lo
  CC     coders/coders_caption_la-caption.lo
  CC     coders/coders_cin_la-cin.lo
  CC     coders/coders_cip_la-cip.lo
  CC     coders/coders_clip_la-clip.lo
  CC     coders/coders_cmyk_la-cmyk.lo
  CC     coders/coders_cut_la-cut.lo
  CC     coders/coders_dcm_la-dcm.lo
  CC     coders/coders_dds_la-dds.lo
  CC     coders/coders_debug_la-debug.lo
  CC     coders/coders_dib_la-dib.lo
  CC     coders/coders_dng_la-dng.lo
  CC     coders/coders_dot_la-dot.lo
  CC     coders/coders_dpx_la-dpx.lo
  CC     coders/coders_fax_la-fax.lo
  CC     coders/coders_fd_la-fd.lo
  CC     coders/coders_fits_la-fits.lo
  CC     coders/coders_gif_la-gif.lo
  CC     coders/coders_gradient_la-gradient.lo
  CC     coders/coders_gray_la-gray.lo
  CC     coders/coders_hald_la-hald.lo
  CC     coders/coders_hdr_la-hdr.lo
  CC     coders/coders_histogram_la-histogram.lo
  CC     coders/coders_hrz_la-hrz.lo
  CC     coders/coders_html_la-html.lo
  CC     coders/coders_icon_la-icon.lo
  CC     coders/coders_inline_la-inline.lo
  CC     coders/coders_info_la-info.lo
  CC     coders/coders_ipl_la-ipl.lo
  CC     coders/coders_label_la-label.lo
  CC     coders/coders_mac_la-mac.lo
  CC     coders/coders_magick_la-magick.lo
  CC     coders/coders_map_la-map.lo
  CC     coders/coders_mat_la-mat.lo
  CC     coders/coders_matte_la-matte.lo
  CC     coders/coders_meta_la-meta.lo
  CC     coders/coders_miff_la-miff.lo
  CC     coders/coders_mono_la-mono.lo
  CC     coders/coders_mpc_la-mpc.lo
  CC     coders/coders_mpeg_la-mpeg.lo
  CC     coders/coders_mpr_la-mpr.lo
  CC     coders/coders_msl_la-msl.lo
  CC     coders/coders_mtv_la-mtv.lo
  CC     coders/coders_mvg_la-mvg.lo
  CC     coders/coders_null_la-null.lo
  CC     coders/coders_otb_la-otb.lo
  CC     coders/coders_palm_la-palm.lo
  CC     coders/coders_pango_la-pango.lo
  CC     coders/coders_pattern_la-pattern.lo
  CC     coders/coders_pcd_la-pcd.lo
  CC     coders/coders_pcl_la-pcl.lo
  CC     coders/coders_pcx_la-pcx.lo
  CC     coders/coders_pdb_la-pdb.lo
  CC     coders/coders_pdf_la-pdf.lo
  CC     coders/coders_pes_la-pes.lo
  CC     coders/coders_pict_la-pict.lo
  CC     coders/coders_pix_la-pix.lo
  CC     coders/coders_plasma_la-plasma.lo
  CC     coders/coders_pnm_la-pnm.lo
  CC     coders/coders_preview_la-preview.lo
  CC     coders/coders_ps_la-ps.lo
  CC     coders/coders_ps2_la-ps2.lo
  CC     coders/coders_ps3_la-ps3.lo
  CC     coders/coders_psd_la-psd.lo
  CC     coders/coders_pwp_la-pwp.lo
  CC     coders/coders_raw_la-raw.lo
  CC     coders/coders_rgb_la-rgb.lo
  CC     coders/coders_rla_la-rla.lo
  CC     coders/coders_rle_la-rle.lo
  CC     coders/coders_scr_la-scr.lo
  CC     coders/coders_sct_la-sct.lo
  CC     coders/coders_sfw_la-sfw.lo
  CC     coders/coders_sgi_la-sgi.lo
  CC     coders/coders_stegano_la-stegano.lo
  CC     coders/coders_sun_la-sun.lo
  CC     coders/coders_svg_la-svg.lo
  CC     wand/wand_libMagickWand_la-animate.lo
coders/svg.c:93:10: fatal error: 'librsvg/rsvg.h' file not found
#include "librsvg/rsvg.h"
         ^
  CC     wand/wand_libMagickWand_la-compare.lo
1 error generated.
make[1]: *** [coders/coders_svg_la-svg.lo] Error 1
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make: *** [install] Error 2
config.log was copied to /Users/dries/Library/Logs/Homebrew
==> Build Environment
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 0.9.2
HEAD: 20ad5702c5bdb89e7a52c0b7407d58dbbf6a9afd
CPU: quad-core 64-bit arrandale
OS X: 10.8-x86_64
Xcode: 4.4
CLT: 4.4.0.0.1.1249367152
X11: 2.7.2 @ /opt/X11
CC: /usr/bin/clang
CXX: /usr/bin/clang++ => /usr/bin/clang
LD: /usr/bin/clang
CFLAGS: -Os -w -pipe -march=native -Qunused-arguments -mmacosx-version-min=10.8
CXXFLAGS: -Os -w -pipe -march=native -Qunused-arguments -mmacosx-version-min=10.8
CPPFLAGS: -I/usr/local/Cellar/gettext/0.18.1.1/include -isystem /usr/local/include -I/opt/X11/include
CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/X11:/opt/X11
LDFLAGS: -L/usr/local/Cellar/gettext/0.18.1.1/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/opt/X11/lib
MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET: 10.8
MAKEFLAGS: -j4
PKG_CONFIG_PATH: /opt/X11/share/pkgconfig:/opt/X11/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/pkgconfig
Error: Failed executing: make install (imagemagick.rb:137)
These existing issues may help you:
    https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/13618
    https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/13638
Otherwise, this may help you fix or report the issue:
    https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/bug-fixing-checklist
```

For the moment I'm running out of possible steps I can take. Somebody knows what is wrong with this installation?

Comment: I have the exact same config and it worked for me. My output was much shorter though:

brew install imagemagick
==> Downloading http://downloads.sf.net/project/machomebrew/mirror/ImageMagick-6.7.7-6.tar.bz2
########################################### 100,0%
==> Patching
patching file configure
Hunk #1 succeeded at 32371 (offset 447 lines).
==> ./configure --disable-osx-universal-binary --without-perl --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.7-6 --enable-shared --disable-static --with-modules --with
==> make install
/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.7-6: 1396 files, 32M, built in 93 seconds

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wasted a lot of time for this one. In the end I did as stated on this site:

http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/27985816073/the-hitchhikers-guide-to-riding-a-mountain-lion

And (the thing that seemed to fix it for me) was running `brew doctor` and fixing every single issue until it did not complain any longer. Now I have imagemagick installed. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah I also encounters the problem，I think `make` is the cause of the conflict.

Before install, I use `brew doctor` to check env, it shows me  following error :

```
Your compilers are different from the standard versions for your Xcode.
If you have Xcode 4.3 or newer, you should install the Command Line Tools for
Xcode from within Xcode's Download preferences.
Otherwise, you should reinstall Xcode.
```

If you install Xcode-4.4 beforehand, then install osx-GCC-4.2, this mistake will appear .

I try to reinstall Xcode-4.4, but it doesn't work. So I just direct compiler installation from the source code.

- curl -O ftp://ftp.imagemagick.org/pub/ImageMagick/ImageMagick.tar.gz
- tar -zxvf ImageMagick.tar.gz
- cd ImageMagick-6.7.8-8
- ./configure --prefix=/usr/local
- make && make install

And then ImageMagick works. But this may lead file storage location has a problem, it will produce some warnings when you use `brew doctor` to check .

---

Recently I tried to reset xcode-path to solve version confict

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

I think this can be a way to solve `make` conflict.

Comment: Of all the solutions out there, this is the only one that worked. Thanx

Answer (score 0):

If anyone reading this is using macports instead of homebrew, you can install ImageMagick (After installing Xcode and the command line tools) with the following command:

```
sudo port install ImageMagick
```